# Ensuring order of execution : javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to load google map JS on a button click ( rather than including in a Head for optimization).

```
     $.when(
           $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&libraries=places")
               .done(function() {
                 console.log('loaded');
               })
        )
        .then(_getCurrentLocation())
        .then(_lookForLatLang())
```

getCurrentLocation is nothing but a geolocation object that browser supports base on that reverse lookup is done.

I want to strictly follow the order of execution of Javascript files, but its not ideally happening. I can see output of getCurrentLocation FIRST & then getScript log.

whats wrong with the script ?

Comment: `getScript` returns a promise.  You don't need `$.when`.

Comment: Check your console for errors (hit F12). I'm sure you'll see some things which will help explain why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback:

```html
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&libraries=places")
    .done(function() {
        console.log('loaded');
    }, function () {
        _getCurrentLocation();
        _lookForLatLang();
    });
```

Comment: Why the extra parens around your function calls?  `(_getCurrentLocation())` can be just `_getCurrentLocation()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
.then(_getCurrentLocation())
```

You just called `_getCurrentLocation` *immediately* and passed the returned value to `then()` (just like any other function call).

You want to pass the function itself.

Comment: Why don't you show the correct code rather than only highlight the wrong code?

Comment: @jfriend00: Because I want to teacher people to understand, not to copy code from StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't buy it.  I think the other answers that show the correct code are better answers.  Text that explains that problem so the OP hopefully understands also makes an answer a better answer, but not at the expense of not actually showing the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&libraries=places")
  .done(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
    _getCurrentLocation();
    _lookForLatLang();
  });
```